# App Crash despite NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

Tags: ios, swift, privacy, info.plist, photolibrary

my app crashs for reason - missing key for Privacy NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription - allthough i add exactly this key to the info.plist file. I converted the projet from Swift 3 to Swift 5. Maybe thats the cause?

I use the photo library for reading and writing. Reading(import) is strangly possible.

Comment: What are you doing exactly with the Photo library. Are you just reading from it or also writing to it ?

Comment: Thanks! Reading exactly is an Art. For EXPORT NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription is obligatory!

Answer (score 0):

For EXPORT images to the library NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription is obligatory! NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is not enought.